# How to wait for something before calling WS

Tags: angular, rxjs

My app use SSO authentication with token which can expires.

While clicking on the "admin" button, I need to call several WS for several part of the page (those calls are not chained).

If my token is expired, first WS call will result in a 401 error. Then I will call for token renewal.
What I'm trying to do is to hold following ws Calls until token renewal is done.

I have something like :

```
private isTokenBeingRenewed: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
...
private handleAccessTokenExpiration(wsCall: Function, growlSuccessMsg: string, growlTitle?: string): Observable<Response> {
        // flag token being renewed
        this.isTokenBeingRenewed.next(true);
        //start token renewal
        return this.oidcSecurityService.refreshSession().flatMap(event => {
            // Call WS again when token is renewed
            return wsCall()
                .catch(error => {
                    return Observable.throw(...);
                })
                .do((res: Response) => {
                    ...
                }, (error: any) => {
                    return Observable.throw(...);
                })
                .finally(() => {
                    // flag token renewal is done
                    this.isTokenBeingRenewed.next(false);
                });
        });
    }
```

And on my ws call function I have :

```
 private handleWSResponse(wsCall: Function,
        showGrowlSuccess: boolean,
        growlTitle?: string,
        growlSuccessMsg?: string): Observable<Response> {

        // Avoid call renew multiple times.
        return this.isTokenBeingRenewed.flatMap(isRenewing => {
            // If token renewal is not in progress, calls WS
            if (!isRenewing) {
                // Call WS
            }
        }
}
```

Problem is, when isRenewing === true, Observable is resolved but doesn't return anything. I don't know how to wait and resolve ONLY if isRenewing = true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use a HttpInterceptor to achieve that!

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
   private authService: AuthService;

   constructor(private inj: Injector) {}

   intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
       if (request.url.includes('/not-authorized')) {
          return next.handle(request);
       }
       this.authService = this.inj.get(AuthService);

       return this.authService.getRawAccessToken()
           .switchMap(token => {
              request = request.clone({
                  setHeaders: {
                      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
                  }
               });
               return next.handle(request);
           });
    }
}
```

The example is not exactly matching your scenario, but the method should do.
Something like that. Here you have to divide APIs which have to get authorized. Then you can check token expiration within an auth service. The Observable the "authservice" provides should only resolve if the token is valid again. Then you have a single point where every call can be controlled from.
That's the easiest way in my opinion.
Furthermore, in such Scenarios, switchMap should be used.

If you are not using Angular here, the same concept can be used either. Just subscribe to the behavioursubject and filter all false values like that. But if you always make an async call to the first service to check if the token is expired you always will lose some calls. You should be able checking expiration by using oidc synchronous:

```
private isTokenBeingRenewed: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);

public handleAccessTokenExpiration(): Observable<boolean> {
    this.isTokenBeingRenewed.next(true);
    //start token renewal
    this.oidcSecurityService.refreshSession()
         .subscribe(event => this.isTokenBeingRenewed.nect(false);
    return this.isTokenBeingRenewed;
}
```

In the caller:

```
public doSth() {
    handleAccessTokenExpiration
        .filter(result => !result)
        .switchMap(result => doWsCall())
        .sunscribe();
}
```

If your ws call is no observable. Just Wrap it.

Answer (score 0):

So what you want to do is, if `token` is renewed, call `wsCall` immediately and if `token` is not renewed, call `handleAccessTokenExpiration`, and then call `wsCall`. You can make use of `switchMap()` to do the "waiting":

```
private handleWSResponse(wsCall: Function,
                         showGrowlSuccess: boolean,
                         growlTitle?: string,
                         growlSuccessMsg?: string): Observable<Response> {

    if (this.isTokenBeingRenewed) {
        return wsCall();
    } else {
       //handle token first
       //arguments here is omitted for brevity
        return this.handleAccessTokenExpiration()
            .switchMap(() => wsCall());
    }
}
```

Or you can do it in one liner:

```
return this.isTokenBeingRenewed ? wsCall() : this.handleAccessTokenExpiration().switchMap(() => wsCall());
```